# How to add an array into an array to become 2 dimension array?

Tags: php, arrays

I retrieve the data from database, the data contain multiple rows of `"Semester", "TimeTableID", "SubjectID", "SubjectName", "FacultyName", "Day", "StartTime", "EndTime", "Location"`.
When I get the data, I want to group them by `"Semester"`.
For example, I have these data retrieved from database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Semester] => Semester 1, 2015
            [TimeTableID] => 11
            [SubjectID] => CSCI2203
            [SubjectName] => VISUAL PROGRAMMING
            [FacultyName] => NAME 0
            [Day] => Tue&Thu
            [StartTime] => 10:15:00
            [EndTime] => 12:00:00
            [Location] => C4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Semester] => Semester 1, 2015
            [TimeTableID] => 12
            [SubjectID] => CSCI2903
            [SubjectName] => FUNDAMENTALS OF NETWORKING
            [FacultyName] => NAME 1
            [Day] => Fri
            [StartTime] => 10:15:00
            [EndTime] => 12:00:00
            [Location] => C13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Semester] => Semester 1, 2015
            [TimeTableID] => 10
            [SubjectID] => CSCI2003
            [SubjectName] => DATA STRUCTURES
            [FacultyName] => NAME 2
            [Day] => Mon&Wed
            [StartTime] => 10:15:00
            [EndTime] => 12:00:00
            [Location] => C6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Semester] => Semester 2, 2015
            [TimeTableID] => 5
            [SubjectID] => CSCI2903
            [SubjectName] => FUNDAMENTALS OF NETWORKING
            [FacultyName] => NAME 3
            [Day] => Fri
            [StartTime] => 08:00:00
            [EndTime] => 09:45:00
            [Location] => LH3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Semester] => Semester 2, 2015
            [TimeTableID] => 3
            [SubjectID] => CSCI3003
            [SubjectName] => INTRODUCTION TO SOFTWARE ENGINEERING
            [FacultyName] => NAME 1
            [Day] => Mon&Wed
            [StartTime] => 08:00:00
            [EndTime] => 09:45:00
            [Location] => C12
        )
)
```

and I want to group them by `"Semester"` like this:

```
Array
(
    [Semester 1, 2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Semester 1, 2015
            [1] => 11
            [2] => CSCI2203
            [3] => VISUAL PROGRAMMING
            [4] => NAME 0
            [5] => Tue&Thu
            [6] => 10:15:00
            [7] => 12:00:00
            [8] => C4
            [9] => Semester 1, 2015
            [10] => 12
            [11] => CSCI2903
            [12] => FUNDAMENTALS OF NETWORKING
            [13] => NAME 1
            [14] => Fri
            [15] => 10:15:00
            [16] => 12:00:00
            [17] => C13
            [18] => Semester 1, 2015
            [19] => 10
            [20] => CSCI2003
            [21] => DATA STRUCTURES
            [22] => NAME 2
            [23] => Mon&Wed
            [24] => 10:15:00
            [25] => 12:00:00
            [26] => C6
        )

    [Semester 2, 2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Semester 2, 2015
            [1] => 5
            [2] => CSCI2903
            [3] => FUNDAMENTALS OF NETWORKING
            [4] => NAME 3
            [5] => Fri
            [6] => 08:00:00
            [7] => 09:45:00
            [8] => LH3
            [9] => Semester 2, 2015
            [10] => 3
            [11] => CSCI3003
            [12] => INTRODUCTION TO SOFTWARE ENGINEERING
            [13] => NAME 1
            [14] => Mon&Wed
            [15] => 08:00:00
            [16] => 09:45:00
            [17] => C12
        )
)
```

This is so far what I have:

```
$Semester = array();
$dataKey = array("Semester", "TimeTableID", "SubjectID", "SubjectName", "FacultyName", "Day", "StartTime", "EndTime", "Location");
for($i = 0; $i < count($Record); $i++)
{
    if(!in_array($Record[$i]['Semester'], $Semester))
    {
        $Semester[$Record[$i]['Semester']] = $Record[$i]['Semester'];
    }
    for($j = 0; $j < count($dataKey); $j++)
    {
        $Semester[$Record[$i]['Semester']] = $Record[$i][$dataKey[$j]];
    }
}
print_r($Semester);
```

`$Record` is array of data which I retrieved from database. But this code will only give me the last value(which is `location`) like:

```
Array
(
    [Semester 1, 2015] => C6
    [Semester 2, 2015] => C12
)
```

Comment: `$Semester[$Record[$i]['Semester']][]`  ?

Comment: You can use `array_values` to get all the values of the array, instead of looping over the `$dataKey` array. And use `array_merge` to concatenate arrays.

Comment: Yes @Barmar is right. If you want that to be few line of codes.

Comment: As well as @Chris you can rearrange the array if you want. For me I always use `foreach` to organize the resulted array.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want the subdirectories to be ordered like that. Indexed arrays should be used for uniform data, you should use associative array for heterogeneous collections.

Comment: Why not make each semester an array of associative arrays, instead of concatenating all the values into an unorganized mess like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through the array and rearrange. I would store each Semester as an array of arrays. Like so:

```
$organized = array();

foreach( $resultsFromDB as $row )
{
    if( ! isset($organized[$row['Semester']]) ) {
        $organized[$row['Semester']] = array($row);
    }else {
        $organized[$row['Semester']][] = $row;
    }
}

print_r($organized);
```

The only thing you need to worry about is the comma (,) in Semester strings. This may not play nice as an index for an array. You could always do a `str_replace()` before setting the Semester as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an associative array to an indexed array using `array_values`. And you can use `array_merge` to concatenate indexed arrays.

```
foreach ($Record as $r)
{
    $s = $r['Semester'];
    if(!in_array($s, $Semester))
    {
        // Get just the values without the keys
        $Semester[$s] = array_values($r);
    } else {
        // Concatenate this record to the sub-array 
        $Semester[$s] = array_merge($Semester[$s], array_values($r));
    }
}
```